# Serializable and DataContract (not versus?)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I am reading some code in my new project and found out the ex-developer was using Serializable and DataContract together.

```
[Serializable]
```

and

```
[DataContract(Namespace="Some.Name.Space", IsReference = true)]
```

I assume WCF will ignore Serializable when there is a DataContract attribute. Is this a correct assumption? If not, what are the benefits to use both at the same time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, `[Serializable]` is ignored if `[DataContract]` is present. This may be useful to e.g. create a type that will have one serialization projection for WCF, and another projection for .NET Remoting (if it is used alongside WCF for legacy reasons).

**UPDATE**: I just ran into a situation in my own code where both `[DataContract]` and `[Serializable]` were necessary. Suppose you have a class with a bunch of auto-generated properties (e.g. `public int Foo {get; set;}`) that you want to use *both* in ASP.NET ViewState and in an ASP.NET Web API JSON endpoint (which uses either the Newtonsoft JSON serializer or the DataContractSerializer). For ViewState to work, you need the class to be  `[Serializable]`. However, this breaks JSON serialization, causing JSON like `{"_k_BackingField123":456}` instead of `{"Foo":456}`, because in the `[Serializable]` model the auto-generated property backing fields get serialized instead of the properties themselves. However, if you *also* add `[DataContract]` to the type (and `[DataMember]` to its properties), both the ViewState and the JSON scenarios work perfectly.