# Can I use DataContract and Serializable together?

Tags: wcf, datacontract, serializable

I am working on WCF service. My all class are already serialize using [Serializable] attribute but due to "k__BackingField" Property Naming problem I used  DataContract  and DataMember attribute.
so Can i use both attribute together like following:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class User
{

  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

is this correct?

I also got similar solution here.
[C# automatic property deserialization of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945585/c-automatic-property-deserialization-of-json/2162000#2162000)

[Serializable and DataContract (not versus?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249334/serializable-and-datacontract-not-versus/4249405#4249405)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found an article on MSDN according to this we can use both attribute DataContract and Serializable together.

> With [Serializable], all fields become part of the data contract (unless they are marked with [NonSerialized]). With [DataContract], only members marked with [DataMember] are included. Note that if a type has both [DataContract] and [Serializable] attributes on it, it will use the [DataContract] mapping

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if the problem is in naming why don't you use

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```